# Detecting if the current user has an active subscription

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, woocommerce-subscriptions

I'm developing a website in WordPress with WooCommerce. I'm using additionally [WC Paid Listings](https://wpjobmanager.com/add-ons/wc-paid-listings/) and [WooCommerce Subscriptions](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/) plugins to handle my work.

The problem is when a user with "subscriber" role with an active subscription login tries to post content every time he/she has to choose a package even if he has an active subscription.

Is there anyone with an idea of how to **detect if the user has an active subscription**, if it returns true then the step choosing package is skipped?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Updated (2019)**

- New conditional function using WooCommerce Subscriptions [`wcs_user_has_subscription()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/filter-reference/#section-3).
- New conditional function using a much lighter code version *(SQL query)*.
- Original enhanced conditional function based on an improved WP_Query.

The following custom conditional functions have an optional argument `$user_id` *(a defined user_id)* and will return **`true`** when the current user (or a defined user) has active subscriptions.

So **this can be done now using 3 different ways** *(that do the same thing)*:

1) Using WooCommerce Subscriptions dedicated conditional function [`wcs_user_has_subscription()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/filter-reference/#section-3):

```
function has_active_subscription( $user_id='' ) {
    // When a $user_id is not specified, get the current user Id
    if( '' == $user_id && is_user_logged_in() ) 
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    // User not logged in we return false
    if( $user_id == 0 ) 
        return false;

    return wcs_user_has_subscription( $user_id, '', 'active' );
}
```

---

2) The same thing with a much lighter SQL query *(added on March 2019)*:

```
function has_active_subscription( $user_id=null ) {
    // When a $user_id is not specified, get the current user Id
    if( null == $user_id && is_user_logged_in() ) 
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    // User not logged in we return false
    if( $user_id == 0 ) 
        return false;

    global $wpdb;

    // Get all active subscriptions count for a user ID
    $count_subscriptions = $wpdb->get_var( "
        SELECT count(p.ID)
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm 
            ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_subscription' 
        AND p.post_status = 'wc-active'
        AND pm.meta_key = '_customer_user' 
        AND pm.meta_value > 0
        AND pm.meta_value = '$user_id'
    " );

    return $count_subscriptions == 0 ? false : true;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

---

3) The original enhanced code, that will also do the same:

```
function has_active_subscription( $user_id=null ) {
    // When a $user_id is not specified, get the current user Id
    if( null == $user_id && is_user_logged_in() ) 
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    // User not logged in we return false
    if( $user_id == 0 ) 
        return false;

    // Get all active subscriptions for a user ID
    $active_subscriptions = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => 1, // Only one is enough
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => $user_id,
        'post_type'   => 'shop_subscription', // Subscription post type
        'post_status' => 'wc-active', // Active subscription
        'fields'      => 'ids', // return only IDs (instead of complete post objects)
    ) );

    return sizeof($active_subscriptions) == 0 ? false : true;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

---

**Update of usage:**

1) USAGE for the current user:

```
if( has_active_subscription() ){ // Current user has an active subscription 
    // do something … here goes your code

    // Example of displaying something
    echo '<p>I have active subscription</p>';
}
```

2) USAGE for a defined user ID:

```
if( has_active_subscription(26) ){ // Defined User ID has an active subscription 
    // do something … here goes your code

    // Example of displaying something
    echo '<p>User ID "26" have an active subscription</p>';
}
```

This code is tested and it works

---

Related answers:

- [WooCommerce Subscriptions - Check if product already has an active subscriber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39095349/woocommerce-subscriptions-check-if-product-already-has-an-active-subscriber)
- [WooCommerce - Get active subscriptions in a list between start / end date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39596477/woocommerce-get-active-subscriptions-in-a-list-between-start-end-date)

Comment: Thanks to Loic it seems the codes working but the problem is when i redirect the page the following error appear Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/xxx/xxxx/wp-content/themes/jobsdojo/header.php:13) in /home2/xxx/public_html/quickextra/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1174.  please one more tip can help

Comment: Thanks @ Loic TheAztec what i tried to overide the package-selection.php

Comment: This code is helpful but beware of implementation if you have large post meta table. It will conduct a full table scan due to lack of index. I just fixed a site that copy/pasted this & had to modify it to set & check a session variable if they had an active subscription & check the user id was not 0 before calling get_posts. They were calling this on pages to display premium content whether a user was logged in or not. get_current_user_id will always return 0 if not logged in. Site was experiencing 2k selects/sec & after my changes optimized to 200/sec. I also added index for meta key/value.

Comment: @mtg169 Thank you (that was an old answer)… I have updated the function code with some enhancements and added 2 other different ways: a much lighter code version *(using a SQL query)* and another one based on wcs_user_has_subscription() WooCommerce Subscriptions conditional function.

Comment: Thanks for keeping all 3 answers across the edit history. Different approaches could be better in different circumstances.

Answer (score 8):

Use `wcs_user_has_subscription()`

```
$has_sub = wcs_user_has_subscription( '', '', 'active' );

if ( $has_sub) {
    // User have active subscription
}
```