# Conditionally add a subscription when product added to cart in WooCommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, woocommerce-subscriptions

Hi Im looking for a code that adds my subscription ID *(2282)* to cart if there is added a normal product but **NOT** if the user is already subscriber.

Feel free to ask questions. I'm in the GMT+1 time zone
Wordpress - 4.8.1
WooCommerce – 3.1.1
WooCommerce Subscriptions - 2.2.11
WooCommerce Memberships – 1.8.8
Theme - Shopkeeper - 2.2.3

**i've looked and tried to fool around with this. With no success**

```
// add item to cart on visit
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'add_product_to_cart' );
function add_product_to_cart() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $product_id = 2282;
        $found = false;
        //check if product already in cart
        if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                $_product = $values['data'];
                if ( $_product->id == $product_id )
                    $found = true;
            }
            // if product not found, add it
            if ( ! $found )
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        } else {
            // if no products in cart, add it
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        }
    }
}
```

How can I conditionally add a subscription when product added to cart for non active subscribers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For WooCommerce subscriptions **I haven't found any function to check if the current user has an active subscription**.

So I have made this answer that still works on WooCommerce 3+ and last WC Subscriptions plugin: [Detecting if the current user has an active subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42403821/detecting-if-the-current-user-has-an-active-subscription)

So using a custom function hooked in woocommerce_add_to_cart action hook and using my conditional function code from my old answer, you will get it working:

```
// Conditional function detecting if the current user has an active subscription
function has_active_subscription( $user_id=null ) {
    // if the user_id is not set in function argument we get the current user ID
    if( null == $user_id )
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    // Get all active subscrptions for a user ID
    $active_subscriptions = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => $user_id,
        'post_type'   => 'shop_subscription', // Subscription post type
        'post_status' => 'wc-active', // Active subscription
    ) );
    // if user has an active subscription
    if(!empty($active_subscriptions)) return true;
    else return false;
}


// Conditionally checking and adding your subscription when a product is added to cart
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'add_subscription_to_cart', 10, 6 );
function add_subscription_to_cart( $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data ) {

    // Here define your subscription product
    $subscription_id = 2282;
    $found = false;

    if ( is_admin() || has_active_subscription() || $product_id == $subscription_id ) return;  // exit

    // Checking if subscription is already in cart
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if ( $cart_item['product_id'] == $subscription_id ){
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    // if subscription is not found, we add it
    if ( ! $found )
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $subscription_id );
}
```

*Code goes in any plugin php file (hooks can be used in function.php file of the active theme).*

The code is tested and works.

---

And if the subscription is removed  from cart, we will do a re-check in checkout:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'check_subscription_in_checkout', 10, 0 );
function check_subscription_in_checkout() {

    // Here define your subscription product
    $subscription_id = 2282;
    $found = false;

    if ( is_admin() || has_active_subscription() || ! is_checkout() ) return;  // exit

    // Checking if subscription is already in cart
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if ( $cart_item['product_id'] == $subscription_id ){
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    // if subscription is not found, we add it
    if ( ! $found )
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $subscription_id );
}
```

Comment: Working (Y) ! Thanks!